# why my list print does not append problem

Tags: python, list, printing, bots

this is a code for telegram (chat application), I want to create a bot when everyone say something create a list and add their user name to the list.
for example this is my `list = []`
when x send a message, list should be = `[(x username)]`
afterwards when y send a message bot should reply this `list = [(x username),(y username)]`

i have the problem whit this because when I print the list, it gives me two separate lists. not one.
for example when Mohamad send a message
it gives me this:

```
[mohammad]
```

this is okay but when Mitra send a message it should be:

```
[Mohammad, Mitra]
```

but it is

```
[Mitra]
```

---

```
from telegram.ext import Updater , CommandHandler , Filters , 
CommandHandler , MessageHandler
from telegram import MessageEntity
from telegram import ParseMode , InputTextMessageContent

updater = Updater("989165404:AAF8DEjyunwrb88-1G8w62cGItzXj1J618g")


def msg_filter(bot , update):
    list = []
    list.append("{}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
    bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = " 
    {}".format(list))

        # bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id , text = " 
     {}".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))
     print(list)

     updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text , 
     msg_filter ))
     updater.start_polling()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is happening because you're resetting the list everytime.
Try defining blank list outside the function msg_filter().

```
list = []

def msg_filter():
    //your code//
```

Tell me if it works.
Happy to help.
Peace out.

Comment: Please check the green tickmark if my solution worked for ya. Thank you!